# How to render 3D object within a Libgdx Actor?

Tags: android, 3d, libgdx

Most of the Libgdx tutorials I found show how to add 2D elements in a 3D world, but I would like to know how to the the opposite, adding 3D elements in a 2D Stage.

I tried adding a background image to the `Stage`, then adding to the `Stage` an `Actor` that renders the model batch and the 3D instances in its draw() method.

But instead, the image isn't drawn and part of the 3D object is hidden.

SimpleGame class

```
public class SimpleGame extends ApplicationAdapter {

    Stage stage;

    @Override
    public void create () {
        stage = new Stage();

        InputMultiplexer im = new InputMultiplexer(stage);
        Gdx.input.setInputProcessor( im );

        Image background = new Image(new Texture("badlogic.jpg"));
        background.setSize(stage.getWidth(), stage.getHeight());
        stage.addActor(background);

        setup();
    }

    private void setup() {
        SimpleActor3D group = new SimpleActor3D();
        group.setSize(stage.getWidth(), stage.getHeight());
        group.setPosition(0, 0);
        stage.addActor(group);
    }

    @Override
    public void render () {
        stage.act();

        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1, 1, 1, 1);
        Gdx.gl.glViewport(0, 0, Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight());
        Gdx.gl.glClear( GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL20.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT );

        stage.draw();
    }
}
```

SimpleActor3D class

```
public class SimpleActor3D extends Actor {

    public Environment environment;
    public PerspectiveCamera camera;

    public ModelBatch modelBatch;
    public ModelInstance boxInstance;

    public SimpleActor3D() {
        environment = SimpleUtils.createEnvironment();
        camera = SimpleUtils.createCamera();
        boxInstance = SimpleUtils.createModelInstance(Color.GREEN);

        modelBatch = new ModelBatch();
    }

    @Override
    public void draw(Batch batch, float parentAlpha) {
        Gdx.gl.glViewport((int)getX(), (int)getY(), (int)getWidth(), (int)getHeight());

        modelBatch.begin(camera);
        modelBatch.render( boxInstance, environment );
        modelBatch.end();

        super.draw(batch, parentAlpha);
    }
}
```

SimpleUtils class

```
public class SimpleUtils {

    public static Environment createEnvironment() {
        Environment environment = new Environment();
        environment.set( new ColorAttribute(ColorAttribute.AmbientLight, 0.4f, 0.4f, 0.4f, 1f) );

        DirectionalLight dLight = new DirectionalLight();
        Color lightColor = new Color(0.75f, 0.75f, 0.75f, 1);
        Vector3 lightVector = new Vector3(-1.0f, -0.75f, -0.25f);
        dLight.set( lightColor, lightVector );
        environment.add( dLight ) ;

        return environment;
    }

    public static PerspectiveCamera createCamera() {
        PerspectiveCamera camera = new PerspectiveCamera(67, Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight());
        camera.position.set(10f, 10f, 10f);
        camera.lookAt(0,0,0);
        camera.near = 1f;
        camera.far  = 300f;
        camera.update();

        return camera;
    }

    public static ModelInstance createModelInstance(Color color) {
        ModelBuilder modelBuilder = new ModelBuilder();

        Material boxMaterial = new Material();
        boxMaterial.set( ColorAttribute.createDiffuse(color) );

        int usageCode = VertexAttributes.Usage.Position + VertexAttributes.Usage.ColorPacked + VertexAttributes.Usage.Normal;

        Model boxModel = modelBuilder.createBox( 5f, 5f, 5f, boxMaterial, usageCode );

        return new ModelInstance(boxModel);
    }
}
```

What I would like :

[image: What I would like]

What I have instead :

[image: What I have instead]

I have tried rendering the model batch directly in the `ApplicationAdapter` `render()` method and it works perfectly, so the problems must lie somewhere with the `Stage` but I can't find how.

Comment: In the Actor's draw method, put batch.end() at the beginning and batch.begin() at the end before the super call. But if you have a lot of these 3d actors, performance will be poor due to all the switching back and forth between batch types.

Comment: Thank you that worked ! I didn't think I had to end the batch as I wasn't using it to draw anything.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem but I needed to render 3d object only once so I came with an idea to render 3d model as a Sprite. In order to do that I rendered my model via modelBatch to frame buffer object instead of default screen buffer and then created a sprite from FBO color buffer.

Sample code below:

```
FrameBuffer frameBuffer = new FrameBuffer(Pixmap.Format.RGBA8888, Gdx.graphics.getBackBufferWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getBackBufferHeight(), true);

Sprite renderModel(ModelInstance modelInstance) {
    frameBuffer.begin(); //Capture rendering to frame buffer.

    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL20.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT | (Gdx.graphics.getBufferFormat().coverageSampling ? GL20.GL_COVERAGE_BUFFER_BIT_NV : 0))
    modelBatch.begin(camera);
    modelBatch.render(modelInstance);
    modelBatch.end();

    frameBuffer.end();

    return new Sprite(frameBuffer.getColorBufferTexture());
}
```

You can always update your sprite texture in a render loop with use of `sprite.setTexture();` method. You can also create an Image from a texture -> `new Image(frameBuffer.getColorBufferTexture());` and use it in Scene2d.