# How to combine Scene2d and Bullet?

Tags: java, libgdx, bullet

I want to display some animation using bullet on top of a scene2d stage.
No interaction with the bullet part is required, its supposed to be only an animation.

If required I can also add the SimpleSimulator (so the file has still around 200 lines, even after removing the stuff I don't need for this example).

The call to `SimpleSimulator#create` basically sets up the world, environment and the objects. (The whole bullet thing is based on https://github.com/xoppa/blog/blob/master/tutorials/src/com/xoppa/blog/libgdx/g3d/bullet/dynamics/step6/BulletTest.java)

```java
public class SimpleExample implements ApplicationListener {

    private class ExampleStage extends Stage {

        public ExampleStage() {

            Image background = new Image(new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("background.png")));
            addActor(background);

        }
    }

    private Camera cam;
    private Stage stage;
    private SimpleSimulator simulator;

    @Override
    public void create() {

        Bullet.init();

        cam = new OrthographicCamera(30, 30);
        cam.lookAt(0f, 1f, 0f);
        cam.near = 0f;
        cam.far = 500f;
        cam.update();

        this.stage = new ExampleStage();

        simulator = new SimpleSimulator();
        simulator.create();

    }

    @Override
    public void render() {

        stage.draw();
        stage.act();

        //simulator.simulate();

        // if added only the bullet part will be animated,
        // if not only scene2d
        // Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0f, 0f, 0f, 1.f);
        // Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL20.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

        simulator.modelBatch.begin(cam);
        simulator.modelBatch.render(simulator.instances, simulator.environment);
        simulator.modelBatch.end();
    }

    public void resize(int width, int height) {}
    public void pause() {}
    public void resume() {}

    @Override
    public void dispose() {
        stage.dispose();
        simulator.dispose();
    }
}
```

I might just miss a simple flag in the render method. If I call the Gdx.gl.glClear method's I only manage to see the one or the other.

I also would like to restrict the bullet animation part to a specific area on the screen, so other elements I want to have on the stage are not obstructed by it, but I have not figured out how to do that yet.

Comment: The glClear lines should be at the beginning of your render method (or at least before you start drawing anything. You are clearing what was drawn to screen on the previous frame. Incidentally, you should call `stage.act()` before `stage.draw()` so you aren't inducing a one frame delay on everything it draws.

Comment: @Tenfour04: I could have sworn I've tried that before, but it seems you are right. At least I see something now, just not what I was expecteing. I'll have a look into it.

Comment: While I was searching I found this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42936070/how-to-render-3d-object-within-a-libgdx-actor. At least his example with the answer in the comment works for me, but my simualtor does something weird there as well.

Comment: @Tenfour04: Now it works. I had played around a bit with the coodrinates of the objects while trying to figure this out, but after reverting the changes it looks fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing the order in the render method as suggested by `Tenfour04` did the trick.
I just update this here to mark this question as answered.

```
    @Override
    public void render() {

        Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stage);

        simulator.simulate();

        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0f, 0f, 0f, 1.f);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL20.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

        stage.act();
        stage.draw();

        simulator.modelBatch.begin(cam);
        simulator.modelBatch.render(simulator.instances, simulator.environment);
        simulator.modelBatch.end();
    }
```